# Repeat Selectize select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, repeater, selectize.js

I have a form where the user can input multiple addresses, city, street+nbr and country.

For this field to be repeated I use the jquery repeater library. For the city field I want to use a selectize input field.

I am trying to repeat those 4 fields when clicking on the button, it copies everything correctly but the selectize field does not contain inputs (i guess this is because they have the same id?) but I don't know how to instantiate another selectize instance on that object.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-12 mb-2 address-repeater">

    <div data-repeater-list="stcity">
        <div class="input-group mb-1" data-repeater-item>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="companystreet"><?=lang("flow_company_street")?></label>
                        <input type="text" id="companystreet" class="form-control" placeholder="<?=lang("flow_company_streetname")?>" name="companystreet" required data-validation-required-message="<?=lang("flow_company_street_validation")?>">
                        <div class="help-block font-small-3"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="companystreetnumber"><?=lang("flow_company_nbr")?></label>
                        <input type="text" id="companystreetnumber" class="form-control" placeholder="<?=lang("flow_company_streetnbr")?>" name="companystreetnumber" required data-validation-required-message="<?=lang("flow_company_nbr_validation")?>">
                        <div class="help-block font-small-3"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="companycity"><?=lang("flow_company_city_or_commune")?></label>
                        <select id="companycity" class="companycity-select" name="companycity" autocomplete="new-password" required data-validation-required-message="<?=lang("flow_company_city_or_commune_validation")?>">
                            <option value="" selected><?=lang("flow_company_select_city_or_commune")?></option>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($citiesbe as $city) {
                                //Values are prefilled from javascript
                                $key = strtolower($city->name_nl) . "," . $city->zip_code;
                                echo "<option value=\"$key\"> $city->name_nl ($city->zip_code)</option>";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <div class="help-block font-small-3"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="companycountry"><?=lang("flow_company_country")?></label>
                        <select id="companycountry" class="companycountry-select" name="companycountry" autocomplete="new-password" disabled>
                            <option value="BE" selected><?=lang("flow_company_country_belgium")?></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" data-repeater-create class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="ft-plus"></i> Add new address
    </button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Custom Show / Hide Configurations
$('.address-repeater').repeater({
    show: function () {
        $(this).slideDown();
    },
    hide: function(remove) {
        $(this).slideUp(remove);
    }
});
```

Since the button is not the selectize element, I don't know how to assign it to the newly created element.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I ran into a similar problem, but couldn't find a solution, so I had to work it out myself. Here's an explanation to the solution I applied to get `selectize` and `jquery.repeater` to work nicely.

First, checking through the browser console, you'll find out that `selectize` removes all the select options except the empty option, and uses it to populate it's own dropdown which is generated via javascript. This becomes a problem for `jquery.repeater` because it only repeats or creates a duplicate based on the initial page load, and not after. So, what gets repeated is the only select option left in the select element, which in this case *(unfortunately)* is the empty select option. Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/sammyskills/pen/ExvKWrr) explaining this, feel free to toggle the category targeting `selectize` in the select element to see for yourself.

So, here are the steps I took to get it to work nicely:

- On repeating of the form (`show()` of the repeater instance), you'll need to delete the duplicated element completely from the DOM.
- Create another select element(s) in the DOM with the preferred *(or same)* attributes/options.
- Instantiate selectize on the newly created select element(s).

I'll suggest you add a class to the `.form-group` wrapper housing the `.companycity-select` select element. This will help to append a new select element at the exact place only, since there are other `.form-group` in the code. Check my solution below:

```
// Assuming your have the select element wrapper as <div class="form-group select-wrapper">
$('.address-repeater').reapeter({
    show: function() {
        $(this).slideDown();

        // Remove the created element
        $(this).find('.companycity-select').remove();

        // Repeater rewrites your name attributes to avoid collisions within the same form, 
        // so we need to follow this same rule
        // Get the length of the currently repeated items, to be used as the index for new elements
        var count = $('div[data-repeater-item]').length;

        // Create the new select element. The select name is based on the new name by repeater
        var new_select_option = '<option value="" selected>Select city or community</option>';
        var new_select_element = '<select id="companycity" class="companycity-select" name="stcity['+count+'][companycity]" autocomplete="new-password" required>'+new_select_option+'</select>';

        // Append newly created element to DOM. Remember the new class added to the form-group?
        $(this).find('.form-group.select-wrapper').append(new_select_element);

        // Create a new instance of selectize on the new select element
        $(this).find('.companycity-select').selectize({
            // Populate your select options data via ajax,
            // see docs: https://selectize.dev/docs.html
            valueField: '',
            labelField: '',
            searchField: [],
            options: []
        });
    }
});
```